# Samsung s7 does not provide it gmail id

Tags: android, gmail, samsung-mobile

Why does Samsung s7 not provide its Gmail id using google accounts programmatically in android?

```html
private static Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        Account account;
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            account = accounts[0];
        } else {
            account = null;
        }
        return account;
    }

    public String GET_EMAIL_ADDRESSES() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS}, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
            //After this point you wait for callback in onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]) overriden method
        } else {
            email = getEmiailID(getApplicationContext());
            System.out.println("CORREO SELECCIONADO: " + email);
        }
        return email;
    }
```

Comment: First, this does not seem to be your original code (spelling errors in method names). Second, how do you expect email to contain anything useful if the condition in your second method evaluates to true? Third, btw where is email declared?

Comment: See i am getting gmail id using the above code on every phone but except samsung S7 edge device.

Comment: You should get +1 for testing your code on every phone... ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your ans. You are great. Please let me know if there is any other permission for getting gmail from phones like S7?